# How can I install the perl-RRD-Simple package on CentOS 7?

Tags: perl, centos

I'm trying to install [TSung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) on CentOS 7, but I'm having trouble installing the dependencies.

When I tried to install perl-RRD-Simple.noarch, yum shows no package available. So I downloaded an RPM file and did:

```
rpm -ivh perl-RRD-Simple-1.43-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm
```

But I got an error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        perl(RRDs) is needed by perl-RRD-Simple-1.43-1.el5.rf.noarch
```

How can I install the perl-RRD-Simple package? RRDtool is already installed.

Answer (score 2):

RRD::Simple depends on [RRDs.pm](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/prog/RRDs.en.html), the Perl bindings for RRDtool. RRDs.pm is in the rrdtool-perl package; on CentOS 7, rrdtool-perl is in the base repo, so you can just do:

```
yum install rrdtool-perl
```

You'll also need to find a different perl-RRD-Simple RPM, since perl-RRD-Simple-1.43-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm is for EL5. The only one I can find for EL7 is [here](http://dries.eu/rpms/perl-RRD-Simple/perl-RRD-Simple).

Alternatively, you can [build your own RPM](http://mag-sol.com/talks/yapc/2008/rpm/rpm.pdf).